# Async JSON console vs value issue

Tags: javascript, json

I've read through dozens of posts trying to get data from a json file and it seems so simple yet I cannot figure out why I cannot get it to work right.  For this code:

```
async function getJASON() {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let object = await response.json();
  console.log(object);
  return object;//If needed, see the comment by Emiel
}

myjson =  getJASON();
```

the console log shows the array

```
{
    "name": "Example Group",
    "users": [
        "admin",
        "releaser"
    ]
}
```

but the variable in developer console shows a promise object
scratching my head now, how can it write a json array to console but not give me back the same thing?  How do I get beyond a promise object so I can use the json data?

Comment: You're not awaiting the call to your async function. `myjson` would hold a  [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which would resolve once the function returns. Side note, I would recommend renaming your function. If I just stumbled across this code I would be very confused about who Jason is and why you need to get him.

Comment: myjson = await getJASON(); fails, I've seen and tried this code before:

Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules (at W81MR3:1514:10)

lol, yes my naming convention needs improvement for sure, typo

Comment: Because it's async function it returns a Promise. the console will print what it receives from the getJASON function (Promise)

Comment: The console didn’t print a promise, it printed the json object thus my confusion on why it is printing one thing and returning another.  Still wondering how to successfully get a json object from a file with JavaScript.  Might just do it with php as this is ridiculous in how confusing it is as is demonstrated by how many questions there are on this very subject.

Answer (score 1):

```
myjson = await getJASON();
console.log(myjson)
// or 
getJASON().then(console.log)
```

Comment: myjson = await getJASON(); fails, I've seen and tried this code before:

Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules (at W81MR3:1514:10)